# Variable might not have benn initialized for final variable and anonymous class

Tags: java, variables, initialization

I wrote this code:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ExtractorTimer=Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
final ScheduledFuture<?> SchedulerHandle;
SchedulerHandle =ExtractorTimer.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(DB.buildConnection()){
                  SchedulerHandle.cancel(false);
            }
        }
     },0, 60,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It gives this:

```
Variable SchedulerHandle might not have benn initialized
```

What is the problem?
How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't see a variable called `ScheduledFuture` in your code.  (BTW, you should avoid naming variables with the first letter as a capital, because they can be easily confused with class names.)

Comment: My point is that that you're probably not showing us the actual error message...

Comment: Excuse me. was a typo.I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Because SchedulerHandle is final and you didn't define it right away, your compiler warns you, that it might not been initialized in the run() method.
Simply do:</s>

> final ScheduledFuture SchedulerHandle = ExtractorTimer.scheduleWithFixedDelay(...

Update: That was simply wrong. Let's see, you want to call DB.buildConnection() every 60 seconds until it returns true. Unfortunately you can't reference SchedulerHandle returned from scheduleWithFixedDelay() in the Runnable you call the method with, because the Runnable has to be defined first - but it doesn't know what SchedulerHandle is, because it doesn't exist at that point.

So an alternative way of canceling the process is to terminate your ScheduledExecutorService, like so:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ExtractorTimer=Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
final ScheduledFuture<?> SchedulerHandle;
SchedulerHandle =ExtractorTimer.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(DB.buildConnection()){
                  ExtractorTimer.shutdown();
            }
        }
    },0, 60,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But note, that if you do this, you can't reuse ExtractorTimer and **any** given task will be canceled! Future schedule()s will also not execute. The only way to make it useable again is to create a new ScheduledExecutorService - that's the drawback of this approach.

So if you are okay using ExtractorTimer only for this one task, everything should be fine.

Comment: doing this has no effect! and still i'm getting the message.

Comment: As an alternative to shutting down the complete ThreadPool the `Runnable` might simply throw a `RuntimeException`. That will stop the task too.

Comment: @A.H. I think yes, although I don't quite unterstand the Java documentation at that point: "If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed. Otherwise, the task will only terminate via cancellation or termination of the executor." So they are "suppressed", not canceled? I don't know if there's a difference.

Comment: A quick tests revealed that `isCancelled==false`, `isDone==true` and `get()` will receive an `ExecutionException` wrapping the original exception. If @snigger can live with that - ok.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is correct.  There actually is a problem here.

The problem arises because of the way that Java handles the use of the `SchedulerHandle` variable within the anonymous `Runnable` class.  When the `Runnable` class is instantiated, a synthetic constructor parameter is used to pass the value of `SchedulerHandle` to the anonymous class.  This value is stored in a hidden attribute, and that's what the `run()` method uses ... not the variable in the scope enclosing the class.

So why does this cause the error?

Well, the mechanism I described above means that `SchedulerHandle` needs to be initialized before the `Runnable` instance is created.  But in fact, it gets initialized later, after the `scheduleWithFixedDelay` call has returned.  So at the time the variable's value is needed it has not been initialized.

Answer (score -3):

Try :

```
final ScheduledFuture<?> SchedulerHandle = null;
```

Comment: ROTFL. That will not really help.

Comment: Give it a try. It solves the problem in Netbeans
Looks pretty logical to me :-)

Comment: Did you notice the upcoming NPE in `SchedulerHandle.cancel(false);` ? And also the assignment to this very final variable? If that really works in Netbeans I wont touch this IDE in the next decade.

Comment: ScheduledFuture<?> SchedulerHandle; variable is not initialized, correct?
Then the call to scheduleWithFixedDelay, which can throw Exception, correct?
If it throws an exception, SchedulerHandle is still not initialized, correct?
So, initialize it with null or handle the Exception

Comment: First point: The variable is `final`. You initialize it. So the next line - an assignment to this very variable - will not compile. If Netbeans does not show you this error... to bad. Second: Whether `scheduleWithFixedDelay` throws an exception or not is irrelevant. The `Runnable` will be executed asynchronously. When this happens  it will throw a NPE due to the line ` SchedulerHandle.cancel(false);
` - the very variable which you pinned down to `null`. And removing the `final` will not work, because then you could not access the variable from inside the `Runnable`.